# self-adjoint subalgebras of matrix algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, operator-algebras

Is there any classification theorem for the self-adjoint matrix subalgebras of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ the algebra of $n \times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: Yes. They are direct products of matrix algebras. this has surely been asked here (and should be done in any sensible textbook on $C^*$-algebras)

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/137655/structure-theorem-for-finite-dimensional-c-algebras-and-their-representation/137704#137704, for example.